# code only runs once per click while trying to implement a growing bar into my code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

The desired outcome is to have a box that can be clicked by the player, and then slowly fill up. I tried using while and for loops after testing if the user clicked the button, but rather than increasing slowly, it only increases a fraction of the entire box. The entire games code is below, but my issue seems to be with lines 70-80.

```
import pygame, sys, time, threading, tqdm

pygame.init()
#Setting up background colors, etc
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
RED = (255,0,0)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
YELLOW =(255,255,0)

#Setting up window and caption
DISPLAYSURF_x = 460
DISPLAYSURF_y = 720
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAYSURF_x,DISPLAYSURF_y))
pygame.display.set_caption('Adventure Capitalist')
logo = pygame.image.load('Logo.png')
menu = pygame.image.load('menu.png')
DISPLAYSURF.fill(WHITE)
cash = 30
amount = 0
barlength = 102
storeBoard = pygame.image.load('storeBoard.png')

def buyDraw(amount, minxbuy, minybuy):
    Font1 = pygame.font.SysFont('monaco', 24)
    buySurface = Font1.render('{0}'.format(amount), True, BLACK)
    buyRect = buySurface.get_rect()
    buyRect.midtop = (75, minybuy)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(buySurface,buyRect)
def cashDraw(cash):
    Font2 = pygame.font.SysFont('monaco', 40)
    cashSurface = Font2.render(' ${0}'.format(cash), True, GREEN)
    cashRect = cashSurface.get_rect()
    cashRect.midtop = (420, 10)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(cashSurface,cashRect)
# amount of item, cost to buy, time taken to complete action, money per run
def capitalist(amount, cost, timez, gain, minxbuy, maxxbuy, minybuy, maxybuy, minxgain, maxxgain, minygain, maxygain, cash):
    print ("ran")
    # Buy button
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(WHITE)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(storeBoard, (0, 0))

    buyDraw(amount, minxbuy, minybuy)
    cashDraw(cash)
    pygame.display.flip()
    button_rect = pygame.Rect(minxgain, minygain, maxxgain, maxygain)
    # Coefficient to calculate the width of the rect for a given time.
    coefficient = maxxgain / timez
    time = 0
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    dt = 0
    done = False
    while True:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                (x, y) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                if x < maxxbuy and x > minxbuy and y < maxybuy and y > minybuy and cash >= cost:
                    DISPLAYSURF.fill(WHITE, (minxbuy+25, minybuy, maxxbuy+30, maxybuy))
                    amount += 1 
                    buyDraw(amount, minxbuy, minybuy)                   
                    print (cash)
                    DISPLAYSURF.fill(WHITE, (375, 0 , 460, 51))
                    cash -= cost
                    cashDraw(cash)
                    pygame.display.flip()

                if x < maxxgain and x > minxgain and y < maxygain and y > minygain and amount > 0:

                                # If mouse is over the button, increase the timer.
                    if time < timez:  # Stop increasing if max_time is reached.

                        time += dt

                        if time >= timez:

                            time = timez

        inc = time * coefficient


        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, BLACK, (minxgain, minygain, inc/2, maxygain/2))


        pygame.display.flip()
        dt = clock.tick(60) / 100





def opening():
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(logo, (155, 50))
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(menu, (0 , 125))

    while True:
        pygame.display.flip()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                (x, y) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                if x < 375 and x > 80 and y < 545 and y > 395:
                             #   1    2      3     4        5        6         7       8     9        10        11       12    13  
                            #amount, cost, time, gain, minxbuy, maxxbuy, minybuy, maxybuy, minxgain, maxxgain, minygain, maxygain, cash
                #   capitalist(0, 5, 1, 1, 21, 41, 21, 41, 120, 204, 20, 41, cash)
                    capitalist(1, 10, 3, 5, 21, 41, 21, 41, 120, 204, 20, 41, cash)

        pygame.display.flip()



opening()
```

Comment: Please try to explain your requirements more clearly. I got the impression that you want a rectangle slowly filled after an user clicked it, but allow the user to continue using your interface. Am I right? What are two loops and import threading for otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how exactly your buttons should behave, but I can tell you how to fix the event handling and logic in your `capitalist` function. Your main problem is that you use the event loop to increase the amount, whereas you rather want to use `pygame.mouse.get_pressed` in the `while` loop in this case to see which mouse buttons are currently pressed. Then check if the `mouse_pos` collides with one of the predefined buttons (`pygame.Rect`s) and run the desired code.

The drawing code should also be separated from the event handling and the game logic. I've got a complete, working example here with some additional side notes (as I said I'm not sure how the buttons should behave, so you have to adjust them as you want):

```
import pygame, sys

pygame.init()
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
GREEN = pygame.Color('green')

DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((460, 720))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

cash = 30
amount = 0
barlength = 102
storeBoard = pygame.Surface((102, 40))
storeBoard.fill((100, 100, 250))
# Side note: Define the fonts once here.
Font1 = pygame.font.SysFont('monaco', 24)
Font2 = pygame.font.SysFont('monaco', 40)


def buyDraw(amount, minxbuy, minybuy):
    buySurface = Font1.render('{0}'.format(amount), True, BLACK)
    buyRect = buySurface.get_rect()
    buyRect.midtop = (75, minybuy)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(buySurface, buyRect)


def cashDraw(cash):
    cashSurface = Font2.render(' ${0}'.format(cash), True, GREEN)
    cashRect = cashSurface.get_rect()
    cashRect.midtop = (420, 10)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(cashSurface, cashRect)


# amount of item, cost to buy, time taken to complete action, money per run
def capitalist(amount, cost, timez, gain, minxbuy, maxxbuy, minybuy, maxybuy, minxgain, maxxgain, minygain, maxygain, cash):
    pygame.display.set_caption('capitalist loop')
    # Define the buttons here.
    buy_button = pygame.Rect(minxbuy, minybuy, maxxbuy, maxybuy)
    gain_button = pygame.Rect(minxgain, minygain, maxxgain, maxygain)
    # Coefficient to calculate the width of the rect for a given time.
    coefficient = maxxgain / timez
    time = 0
    dt = 0

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        # pygame.mouse.get_pressed() returns a tuple of zeros and ones that
        # show you which mouse buttons are currently being held down.
        mouse_pressed = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        # Use the collidepoint method of the rects to see if they collide with the mouse.
        # `mouse_pressed[0]` is the left mouse button.
        if buy_button.collidepoint(mouse_pos) and mouse_pressed[0] and cash >= cost:
            amount += 1
            print(cash)
            cash -= cost

        if gain_button.collidepoint(mouse_pos) and mouse_pressed[0] and amount > 0:
            # If the mouse is over the button, increase the timer.
            if time < timez:  # Stop increasing if max_time is reached.
                time += dt
                if time >= timez:
                    time = timez

        inc = time * coefficient

        # Draw everything and then flip the display.
        DISPLAYSURF.fill(WHITE)
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, BLACK, (minxgain, minygain, inc/2, maxygain/2))
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, BLACK, buy_button, 2)
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, BLACK, gain_button, 2)
        buyDraw(amount, minxbuy, minybuy)
        cashDraw(cash)

        pygame.display.flip()
        dt = clock.tick(60) / 1000  # dt is the passed time in seconds.


def opening():
    pygame.display.set_caption('opening loop')
    rect = pygame.Rect(20, 20, 100, 70)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                # Collidepoint with the event.pos to see if the mouse
                # collides with the button.
                if rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    # Named arguments make the code more readable. Passing
                    # so many arguments can be a code smell and indicates
                    # that the code could probably be refactored.
                    capitalist(
                        amount=1, cost=10, timez=3, gain=5, minxbuy=21,
                        maxxbuy=41, minybuy=21, maxybuy=41, minxgain=120,
                        maxxgain=204, minygain=20, maxygain=41, cash=cash)

        DISPLAYSURF.fill(WHITE)
        # Draw the orange start button.
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, (200, 100, 10), rect)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)  # Call clock.tick here as well.

opening()
```

Comment: is there any way to make so it increases the bar after one click, rather than while holding down?

Comment: Sure, define a boolean variable, set it to `True` when a button is pressed, then check if the variable is `True` in the while loop and if yes, in- or decrease the desired value. If you just want to click the button once, you can use the event loop again.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not have 2 main loops. Neither nested nor threaded. There should be only one loop checking the event queue. If you need threading, then you should create your own event distribution in the main loop or manually manage the event queue. Take and remove all events in main-main loop except those needed in the other one. And the other loop should remove only itsown events.
2. Do not draw directly to display surface. It is better to have one surface that you modify and then you blit it fully or parts of it to the screen and flip()/update() it. Sometimes treating display surface as any other causes problems.
3. Perhaps you should use subsurfaces to simplify your task of filling-in rectangles.

When you tidy your code  up a little, the problem should go away or it will be more visible.

Comment: So remove the for loop, and make the while check event type...?

Comment: No-no, the for loop cycles through all events the get() function removed from the event queue. That's all right. The issue is two while loops you have. For the same purpose, both affecting the event queue. A main loop is the loop that controls the interface's event system and decides what to do when some event occurs. And it is the best to have only one of those.

Comment: ohhhhh, ok. So ill put the opening function in the first while loop. Thanks for the help